# Laravel Queues: How to process one set of jobs only after another set of jobs are processed?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two sets of jobs:

- **Set1:** Job A, Job B, Job C
- **Set 2:** Job D, Job E, Job F

How can I process all the jobs in **Set1** and then process the jobs in **Set2**?

I tried **job chaining**. But job chaining stops processing the jobs if its previous job is failed. I want to process them all even if one of them is failed.

It should process all the jobs in **Set1**(A,B,C), and the process of B and C should not stop if the process of job A failed.
When all the jobs of **Set1** are processed(no matter failed or succeeded) It should pick up jobs in **Set2** to process.

The order of the jobs is not priority here. They can be processed in any order.
The **only rule** is that jobs in **Set2** should only be processed after all the jobs in **Set1** are processed.

I cannot work with **delayed dispatch** because the time taken to process **Set1** of jobs varies very highly.

Answer (score 1):

This can now be done with [Job Batching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-batching) in Laravel 8.x:

```php
$batch = Bus::batch([
    new ImportCsv(1, 100),
    new ImportCsv(101, 200),
    new ImportCsv(201, 300),
    new ImportCsv(301, 400),
    new ImportCsv(401, 500),
])->then(function (Batch $batch) {
    // All jobs completed successfully...
})->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) {
    // First batch job failure detected...
})->finally(function (Batch $batch) {
    // The batch has finished executing...
})->dispatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

The job chaining in Laravel is based on the fact that it will no execute the next jobs if current one fails.

You can use events. Each job has 2 methods `handle()` and `failed()`. You can emit events either when job is executed successfully or it is failed. See below example :

For example :

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Exception;
use App\Something;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class JobA implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $something;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  Something $somethin
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Something $something)
    {
        $this->something = $something;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @param  AudioProcessor  $processor
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Execute Job on something
        event(new JobAHandled($something));
    }

    /**
     * The job failed to process.
     *
     * @param  Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        // Send user notification of failure, etc...
        event(new JobAFailed($something, $e));
    }
}
```

Now, you can call the next job by listening to events `JobAHandled` and `JobAFailed`. This will give you control that even if you are continuing the next job execution, you know what the earlier job failed. You can log that if needed.

Then you can do the same for other jobs independent of set it is in.

Also make sure if you try  the job, then the further jobs will be executed again as considering your case the failed event will execute the next job as well.

Comment: This will emit events for the specific job. How can i know all the jobs in the specific set are processed? what i am trying to achieve is process jobs D,E,F only after the jobs A,B,C are processed.

Comment: @SrinathReddyDudi did you ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Isaiahiroko No. The closest i can get to is delay the processing of set 2 jobs with the max amount of time set 1 jobs take to complete.

Comment: thanks @SrinathReddyDudi. Might fall back to that eventually.

Comment: OF COURSE that's how job chaining works in Laravel, and OF COURSE that's why the OP is asking for an ALTERNATIVE to job chaining.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to create a JobSet job and a JobWorker job.

So the Job set takes your new JobWorker("A"), JobWorker("B"), JobWorker("C") as an argument and then dispatches all of them.

```
dispatch(new JobSet(new JobWorker("A"), new JobWorker("B"), new JobWorker("C")));
```

and the "JobSet" job for inspiration

```
class JobSet implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $a;
    private $b;
    private $c;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(JobWorker $a, JobWorker $b, JobWorker $c)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        $this->c = $c;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        dispatch($this->a);
        dispatch($this->b);
        dispatch($this->c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is for dispatching a set of jobs. My question is how to process a specific set of jobs only after all the jobs in the previous set are processed?

Answer (score -1):

You can dispatch them to different queues:

```
A::dispatch()->onQueue('set1');
B::dispatch()->onQueue('set1');
C::dispatch()->onQueue('set1');

D::dispatch()->onQueue('set2');
E::dispatch()->onQueue('set2');
F::dispatch()->onQueue('set2');
```

and run a worker that makes sure set1 is empty before checking set2:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=set1,set2
```

> To start a worker that verifies that all of the `high` queue jobs are processed before continuing to any jobs on the `low` queue, pass a comma-delimited list of queue names to the `work` command:
>
> ```
> php artisan queue:work --queue=high,low
> ```
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker

**Edit:**

You can solve `set1` jobs from User2 delaying the `set2` jobs from User1 by *starting more workers*.

Comment: This works for only one instance of each set. For example if there are ten users and they dispatched different instances of set1 and set2, Then the jobs of set2 will only be processed if the set1 queue is empty. That means the jobs in set2 should wait until all the jobs in set1 are processed. This makes every job in set2 queue of every user to wait until all the jobs in set1 queue are processed. I want them to process the jobs as soon as all the jobs in set1 queue are processed which belongs to that user. Not until all the jobs in set1 queue are processed.

Comment: @SrinathReddyDudi it might help to update the question, because there's no mention of the queues being per-user. If I'm understanding you correctly, then I can't imagine why you would want to do it that way; a specific example of why it needs to work that way might be helpful. Why does the order matter at all if **set2** jobs for a specific user are allowed to process regardless of whether or not their **set1** jobs were successful? If other users adding set1 jobs is delaying the set2 jobs from processing, can't you simply start more workers so that the queue isn't constantly full?